# jQuery: Change the EventType using delegate

Tags: jquery

Currently have the following code:

```
$('#thumbs').delegate('img','hover', function(){
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
});
```

But I want to swap the image back onmouseout. I've tried adapting the delegate to use the onmouseover EventType, and then planned to add a second onmouseout function, but for some reason changing the 'hover' to 'onmouseover' is not producing the expected result, and no error.

Any thoughts why this might be? Also, happy for suggestions of a better way of achieving the desired result.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $large = $('#largeImage').data('src', $('#largeImage').attr('src'));
$('#thumbs').on('mouseenter', 'img', function () {
    $large.attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
}).on('mouseleave', 'img', function () {
    $large.attr('src', $large.data('src'));
});
```

PoC: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7nr3h/)

Comment: @Graeme If this works for you, Then consider it as accepted. :)

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Done - I had to wait a few minutes before I could accept the answer. Hence the gap between my comment and accepting the answer. Thanks